# Know the int value from .htaccess redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having a profile system. I setted up example.com/player/?id=1 redirect to be example.com/player/1, I'm wondering how do I know after there redirected to know its userid number 1? and not for my site to go 404 on me.

.htaccess

```
# Make bloxplays.com/profile/?id=1 to bloxplays.com/profile/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /player/([^\?]*)\?id=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /player/%3/%2?%4 [L,R=301]
```

[404 Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3vpX.png)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding URL rewriting. For _friendly_ URLs, you actually want to rewrite `/profile/1` to `profile/index.php?id=1`. The idea is to take a friendly URL and rewrite it (internally) in a way your application (PHP script) can interpret

Comment: oh no. I rewritten profile/index.php?var=arg to profile/arg, Im wondering how I'm suppose to know what the arg is

Comment: You need to implement the other direction as well. When some client requests `/profile/arg`, then you need to rewrite this to `profile/index.php?var=arg` _internally_, so that you script can then access the GET parameter `var` the usual way.

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

# externally redirect profile/index.php?id=1 to /profile/1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?player/?$ /player/%1 [R=301,END]

# internally rewrite /profile/1 to profile/index.php?id=1
RewriteRule ^/?player/(\d+)/?$ /player/id=$1 [QSA,END]
```

Then you can, as usual, get the actual numeric `id` from php's superglobals, so `$_GET['id']` in this case.

This assumes that a request to `/player/` is somehow mapped to a processing php script in your setup. Your question indicates that is the case which is why I did not further elaborate on that.

Depending on your actual application logic (the references it sends out or generates) you do not need to first redirection. But you definitely need to rewrite incoming requests to something php is able to process. Your application logic definitely should only use references of the form `/player/1`, that first redirection is only for old references that got bookarked somewhere or if parts of your application logic have not yet been fixed to use the new reference pattern.

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's DOCUMENT_ROOT folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).